# How to replace all items in an array of doubles with the same value

Tags: c#

So lets say we have an array of doubles like this one that is later used for other stuff.

```
double[] myArray = new double[25];
```

How would I go about replacing all the values in that array with a set value?

Comment: `var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 25).Select(_ => 0d).ToArray();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are flashier ways, but

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; ++i){
    myArray[i] = foo; /*the new value*/
}
```

is clear and simple.

Comment: wouldn't it better if we define it like `i < myArray.Length`?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad: Of course you're correct. I've pinched that.

Answer (score 6):

The "flashy" way (simply create a new array):

```
var array = Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).ToArray();
```

Or

```
Array.ConvertAll(array, e => value);
```

Comment: Showoff ;-) Have an upvote.

Comment: I think instead of `count` better to write myArray.Length?

Comment: `Repeat` is less efficient than the for-loop approach and `ConvertAll` is made for a different purpose(convert the type), so a bit misleading. It's also using the for-loop[[source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,f4af030bcf8c8991,references)].

Comment: Flashy ways will create new instance of array instead of updating existed one

Comment: @TimSchmelter Totally aware of that ^^. I just wanted to complete Bathsheba's answer since he mentioned *flashy* ways. There are of course countless other ways of abusing built in methods for this purpose.